# Get Resources\Raw Path in .NET Maui

Tags: path, resources, maui

I have an application which uses a SQLite database to store data locally. I get the path to and open the database using:

```
string dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "mydatabase")
db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
```

I have created an example database (example.db3) and copied this to the Resources\Raw folder with the Build Action MauiAsset.
My question is how do I get the path to this database file so I can use

```
string dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine("*path to Resources\Raw foldder*", "example.db3");
```

to get the full path to open the example database.
I have tried searching but the best I can get is using FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync but this opens the file for stream reading whereas I need to get the path.
Ideally the method would work on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3270.

Thanks for your feedback and support.

Answer (score 0):

To get the absolute path of the MauiAsset resource file you can use the following code:

```
using var resourceStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync('myMauiResourceName');
if (resourceStream is FileStream)
{
string absolutePath = (resourceStream as FileStream).Name;
}
```